# Count All Rows That meet Condition For A Given Month

Tags: sqlite

I need to make a SQLite query for something I just can't quite wrap my brain around.

I have a database table with a bunch of "issues". And each "issue" has a createddate, and resolutiondate.

```
id        createddate     resolutiondate
-------------------------------------------
1          2019-04-18      2019-08-18
2          2019-04-20      2019-04-21
3          2019-05-08      2019-06-05
etc....
```

What I need to do, is count how many "issues" every month in the past 12 months, had a created date <= that month, and where the resolutiondate is > that month. I want a table that looks like this:

```
Month         No. Of Issues Not Resolved But Existed That Month
---------------------------------------------------------------
2019-04       20
2019-05       17
2019-06       15
etc...
```

I'm struggling, because I essentially need to check every row multiple times, for every month it's created date is <= that month, and it hasn't been resolved yet. The count for a particular issue could increase the value for "No. Of Issues" for both April 2019 AND May 2019, for example, if it wasn't resolved for 2 months. I'm not sure how to check all rows multiple times.

I have to do it in SQLite.

My current attempt that doesn't seem to be working:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT substr(createddate, 1, 7) AS created
FROM {{ project_key }}
GROUP BY substr(createddate, 1, 7)
) a JOIN (
    SELECT  substr(createddate, 1, 7) AS created,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN julianday(substr(resolutiondate, 1, 10)) >= julianday(substr(created, 1, 10)) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "No. Issues Not Resolved"
    FROM {{ project_key }}
    GROUP BY substr(createddate, 1, 7)
) b ON b.created = a.created
```

Comment: Please include a sample table containing the original data.  It is very hard to piece together a query using data which we can't see.

Comment: At least change the format of your dates to a comparable format like YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recursive `CTE` that returns the past 12 months and a `left join` to the table:

```
with months as (
  select strftime('%Y-%m', 'now', '-1 year') month
  union all 
  select strftime('%Y-%m', strftime('%Y-%m-%d', month || '-01', '+1 month') )
  from months 
  where month < strftime('%Y-%m', 'now', '-1 month')
)   
select m.month, 
  count(id) [No. Of Issues Not Resolved But Existed That Month] 
from months m left join tablename t
on strftime('%Y-%m', t.createddate) <= m.month and strftime('%Y-%m', t.resolutiondate) > m.month
group by m.month
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fUEGGWg5Hw7NZumhdhMve1/1).
Results:

```
| month   | No. Of Issues Not Resolved But Existed That Month |
| ------- | ------------------------------------------------- |
| 2019-02 | 0                                                 |
| 2019-03 | 0                                                 |
| 2019-04 | 1                                                 |
| 2019-05 | 2                                                 |
| 2019-06 | 1                                                 |
| 2019-07 | 1                                                 |
| 2019-08 | 0                                                 |
| 2019-09 | 0                                                 |
| 2019-10 | 0                                                 |
| 2019-11 | 0                                                 |
| 2019-12 | 0                                                 |
| 2020-01 | 0                                                 |
```